# Message with Embeded image not work in JavaMail

Tags: jakarta-mail

It is part of code. When i dont use this code  message sending.

```
messageBodyPart=new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource fds=new FileDataSource("btn2.png");
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID","<image>");
            messageBodyPart.addHeader("Content-Type","image/png");
            messageBodyPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

But when i add this code message not sending. 
And this is full code.

```
Properties props=System.getProperties();
            String fromm="ffff@ffff.fffff.fff";
            String pass="ffffffffff";
            String to="afffffffffff@gmail.com";


            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable",true);
            props.put("mail.smtp.host","ggg.ggg.ggg.gggg");
            props.put("mail.smtp.user",fromm);
            props.put("mail.smtp.password",pass);
            props.put("mail.smtp.port","587");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth",true);
            Session session=Session.getInstance(props,null);
            MimeMessage message=new MimeMessage(session);

            InternetAddress from=new InternetAddress(fromm);
            message.setSubject("Salam mailiniz var");
            message.setFrom(from);
                                         message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(to));

            Multipart multipart=new MimeMultipart();
            BodyPart messageBodyPart=new MimeBodyPart();
            String htmlText="<H1>Hello from the outside Hello, can you hear me?</H1><img src=\"cid:image\">";
            messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText,"text/html; charset=utf-8");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            messageBodyPart=new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource fds=new FileDataSource("btn2.png");
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID","<image>");
            messageBodyPart.addHeader("Content-Type","image/png");
            messageBodyPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            message.setContent(multipart);


            Transport transport=session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect("mail.mct.gov.az",fromm,pass);
            transport.sendMessage(message,message.getAllRecipients());
```

Comment: What does "not sending" mean?  Do you get an exception?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?

Comment: javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
        java.io.FileNotFoundException: logoMail.png (No such file or directory)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:930)
        at mailTest.sendMailTestImage(mailTest.java:67)
        at mailServlet.processRequest(mailServlet.java:132)
        at mailServlet.doGet(mailServlet.java:21)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)

Comment: java classes and logoMail.png are in same directory. And i changed directories to  ./logoMail.png or  /logoMail.png  and logoMail.png.Every time i get same File not found exceptions. Java class cant see img path.

Comment: And i tested code it in server,not in local computer. I dont know how i must write path,  my servlet can see this path.Do i must put it in web WEB-INF or in src or etc.?

Comment: For a file in your web application, use the [ServletContext.getRealPath](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath-java.lang.String-) method to get the real path of the file to attach.

Comment: Thnx, it helps me.

Comment: And my other question is about design for mail. I write html in string.   String htmlText="<H1>Hello</H1><img src=\"cid:image\">";   How i can  include in simple .java class  jsp. Because its diffucult whrite in string  for big html. i want put this degisn in jsp, and then call it from javaMail class. Can i send .jsp as mail?

Comment: You can't directly send a .jsp file.  There are a lot of alternatives for generating the html content that you would put in a mail message, depending on your requirements.  Post a new question and describe your requirements.  In the end, if you can get the html content in a String or an InputStream or a File, you can easily include it in a mail message.

Comment: ok.I will try. it. Thnx.